# Cual puede ser el error para exportar solo lo mostrado

Tags: exportar, reporte

quiero pedirles el favor de verificar cual es el error en este codigo, en primera instancia estoy incursionando en laravel y pues como veran en el codigo hasta ahora inicio unos pinitos,
La idea es que al hacer la busqueda por documento, nombre.. etc... eso me otorga una salida algo asi como esto.
[image: Reporte]

[image: Este es el reporte que genera]

aca el codigo que estoy empleando.

INDEX.BLADE.PHP

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <section class="section">
        <div class="section-header">
            <h3 class="page__heading">Reportes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-body">
          <div class="container">
 
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Creacion de Reportes</h5>  
                  {{Form::open(['route'=>'reportes.index','method'=>'GET','class'=>'form-inline pull-right'])}}

                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <p class="card-text">Digite Dato a generar reporte</p>  
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> 
                      <tr>
                        <td> 
                            <div class="col order-1">
                            <p> --Busqueda de datos por documento-- </p>
                            {{Form::text('documento', null, ['class' => 'form-group col', 'placeholder'=>'# Documento'])}}
                          </div> 
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                          <div class="col order-2">
                            <p> --Busqueda de datos por Nombre-- </p>
                            {{Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-group col', 'placeholder'=>'Nombre'])}}
                          </div>
                        </td> 
                        <tr>
                        <td> 
                          @if(!$categorias=="")
                        <div class="col order-3-sm">
                            <p> --Busqueda de datos por Operacion-- </p>
                            <select name="opera" class="form-group col-sm">
                              <option value=""> -- Seleccione Operacion --  </option>
                              @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                                  <option value="{{ $categoria->codigo }}"> {{ $categoria->name }} </option> 
                            @endforeach 
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                          <div class="col order-1">
                            <p> --Busqueda de datos por fecha proceso-- </p>
                            {{Form::date('date', null, ['class' => 'form-group col', 'placeholder'=>'Fecha'])}}
                          </div> 
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr> 
                        <td> 
                          <div class="col order-2">
                            <p> --Busqueda de datos por detalle-- </p>
                            {{Form::text('detalle', null, ['class' => 'form-group col', 'placeholder'=>'Detalle'])}}
                          </div>
                        </td> 
                        <td> 
                          <div class="col order-3">
                            <p> --Busqueda de datos por concepto-- </p>
                            {{Form::text('concepto', null, ['class' => 'form-group col', 'placeholder'=>'Concepto'])}}
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                  <div class="col order-5">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  {{Form::close()}}

          @endif
          @if(!$reportes=="")  
          <div class="table-responsive"> 
            <h5 class="card-title">Resultado del Reporte</h5>   
                    
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Documento</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Nombre </th>
                    <th scope="col">Operacion</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo Cta</th>  
                    <th scope="col">Num Cta</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Aporte</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha Proceso</th>
                    <th scope="col">Concepto B</th>
                    <th scope="col">Info SECC</th>
                    <th scope="col">Detalle</th>  
                    <th scope="col">Cod. unico Cargue</th>                                   
                    <th scope="col">Acciones</th> 
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ $reporte->num_id_receptor  }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $reporte->nombre_receptor }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $reporte->codigo_opera }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $dato_tipo_cta  }}{{--Tipo de la cuanta--}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $dato_cta  }}{{--Numero de la cuanta--}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $reporte->valor_ope_entera }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $reporte->fecha_proceso }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $reporte->concepto1 }}</td> 
                  <td>{{ $reporte->concepto2 }}</td> 
                  <td>{{ $reporte->detalle_devol }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $reporte->unico_cargue }}</td>
                  <td>
                    @endforeach
                  </td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
<a href="{{ route('reportes.export', $reporte) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><p>Descargar Reporte en Excel</p></a> 
                <a href="{{ route('reportes.exportpdf', $reporte) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><p>Descargar Reporte en PDF</p></a> 
                  <div class="pagination justify-content-end">
                      {!! $reportes->links() !!}
                  </div>
                  @else
                  <p> No se han Digitado datos </p>
                @endif
            </div>
      </section>
  @endsection
```

REPORTECONTROLLER.PHP

```
public function export(Carga $result) 
    {
    return Excel::download(new ExportCarga('reportes.export', $result), 'gas.xlsx');
    }
    /*  public function export($reporte)
    {
        return Excel::download(new ExportCarga, 'reportes.xlsx');
    } */
    public function exportpdf($reporte)
    {
        
        /* Excel::create('Datos users pdf', function($excel) use ($reporte){
            $excel->sheet('Datos', function($sheet) use ($reporte){
                $datos = Carga::find($reporte);
                $datas = $datos->datas;
                $sheet->fromArray($datas); 
        });
    })->export('xlsx'); */
    }
```

EXPORTCARGA.PHP

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Carga;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
Use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ExportCarga implements FromView

{
    protected $view;
    protected $result;
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct($result, $resultados)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->resultados = $resultados;
    }
    public function view(): View{
        return view($this->result,
         $this->resultados);
    }
    public function query()
    {
        return Carga::query()->where('*', $this->year);
    }
    
    /* public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'num_id_receptor',
            'nombre_receptor',
            'codigo_banc_receptor',
            'oficina_cta_recepbbva',
            'cta_recp_nachan',
            'num_cuenta_nachan',
            'oficina_cta_recepbbva',
            'numero_cta_repbbva',
            'valor_ope_part_entera',
            'fecha_proceso',
            'concepto1',
            'concepto2',
            'detalle_devol',    

        ];
    }
    public function collection()
    {
         $datos = DB::table('cargas')->select(
            'num_id_receptor',
            'nombre_receptor',
            'codigo_banc_receptor',
            'oficina_cta_recepbbva',
            'cta_recp_nachan',
            'num_cuenta_nachan',
            'oficina_cta_recepbbva',
            'numero_cta_repbbva',
            'valor_ope_part_entera',
            'fecha_proceso',
            'concepto1',
            'concepto2',
            'detalle_devol')->get();
         return $datos;

    } */
}//return (new ExportCarga('documento')->download('Des_X_DOC.xlsx'));
/* public function collection()
{
    return Carga::all();
}
 */
```

He tenido que colocar en comentario bastante codigo para que pueda arrojarme el resultado de la consulta, ya que al no colocarlo de esta forma me arroja error, la consulta funcionara correctamente lo que no funciona es la exportacion a excel, me podrian colaborar.?

Muchas gracias.